# Font-size issues when reproducing a Word document into a website

Tags: html, css

I have a Microsoft Word document which uses a **10pt Arial** font. I have re-created this document with HTML/CSS, specifying `font: normal 10pt Arial;` in my stylesheet. When I print from the web page (from Chrome), the text appears significantly smaller.

I have my text wrapped in a 800px-wide container on my website. Might this be a cause? Besides this, to be honest I'm completely out of ideas & any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be because you are specifying font sizes in `pts`. `pts` are pretty much inconsistent across platforms and do not scale. (`px` don't scale either) Try using `em`.
See Also: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/font-size, [CSS Font-Size  em vs. px vs. pt vs. percent](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

(You will have to provide a sample of your HTML to get a more concrete answer)

Comment: I don't care how it looks on screen, but it needs to look the same on paper. I figured that since the pt is based on inches it would look the same but ..it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting your font-size to pixels or ems? I believe 10pt would roughly translate to 13px.